# VBA to change cell color based on current color

Tags: excel, vba, colors, color-scheme

I'm having an a lot of excel spreadsheets with a color theme that doesn't match the color theme of my company. 
For instance I need to change cells with a RBG value of `204,255,255` to `179,212,85`. Is there a way of doing it with a VBA?

Comment: Do you want to change the cell's ***font colour*** or ***background colour***?

Comment: Cell background colour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below to change all cells color in `Rng` from `RGB(204, 255, 255)` to `RGB(179, 212, 85)`.

```
Sub ChangeCellColor()

Dim Rng As Range, C As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Rng = Range("A1:E10") ' modify this range according to your needs
For Each C In Rng
    If C.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 255, 255) Then C.Interior.Color = RGB(179, 212, 85)
Next C
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Works just as i needed